# Parsing folder structure with $HOME in the name

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

So I am a making a simple backup script, it will be run every hour. All this script does, is make a backup directory and copy files:

```
./backup/'$HOME'/Documents/todo.txt
```

**backup structure**

```
- backup
    - '$HOME'
        - Documents
             - todo.txt
        - Pictures
    - etc
        - ....
```

I keep the home variable in the name of the folder so it's not bound to one user.

Now, I am trying to make a restore script, which copies all the files in the backup folder, but my problem is, when I echo the structure, the `$HOME` part is not parsed and echoed directly:

**What it echos as:**

```
/$HOME/Documents/todo.txt
```

**What I want it to echo as**

```
/home/myuser/Documents/todo.txt
```

The code I am using to loop over each file in the backup file and try and copy the file to the location:

```
for file in $(find backup -type f); do
    echo "$file" | cut -c 7- | xargs -I {} cp $file {} 
done
```

But, of course, this won't work, because the `$HOME` folder in my `backup` folder is not parsed to a variable. So is it possible to parse variable in a string to make them act like variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints:

- Use `eval` to interpret the variable.
- Don't loop over `find` results, rather use `find -exec`.
- Use `bash` substring removal instead of `cut`.
- Use `rsync` instead of `cp`.
- Create directories before copy.

```bsh
find backup -type f -exec sh -c '
    mkdir -p "$(eval dirname "${1#*/}")";
    rsync -av "$1" "$(eval printf "${1#*/}")"
' find-sh {} \;
```

---

Or better just use `rsync` in the first place which does exactly what you want:

```
rsync -av backup/\$HOME/ $HOME/
```